# could anyone suggest cross source code reference tool?

Tags: linux, cross-reference

I've tried to use `opengrok`, `lxr`, `cxref`. no one didn't work properly or unobvious in installation and configuration. Does anyone know some easy to use tool for C/C++? And it's better if the tools knows a lot of languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried basic ctags?

[CTags sourceforge page](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)

OpenGrok uses ctags and requires it to be installed properly as a precondition, so it is certainly easier to install.  It supports 41 different programming languages and is extremely easy to use.  It's a very popular and widely used tool as it's interface is simple commandline.  It integrates with vi, emacs, and similar tools.

Otherwise, you may have better luck finding answers if you post specific questions on issues you encounter while installing or using specific packages.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/).